# Makefile with relative library not being found

Tags: c++, makefile

I am working on a project and decided to use Boost's regex classes. So I compiled only the regex class and moved libboost_regex.a to a subfolder regex in my project dir. How can I get this file linked?

I have the following makefile:

```
rm=/bin/rm -f
CC= clang++
PROGNAME= story
CFLAGS= -L ./regex
LIBS=-llibboost_regex

SRCS = main.cpp  Environment.cpp 
OBJS = main.o Environment.o 

.cpp.o:
    $(rm) $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.cpp -o $*.o

all: $(PROGNAME)

$(PROGNAME) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(PROGNAME) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines:

```
CFLAGS= -L ./regex
LIBS=-llibboost_regex
```

Should be:

```
LDFLAGS= -L./regex
LIBS= -lboost_regex
```

`LDFLAGS` being for the linker and the `lib` prefix not being needed for libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in your case is probably just:

```
LIBS=-L./regex -lboost_regex
```

or

```
LIBS=./regex/libboost_regex.a
```